# Doctrine Native Query does not load related entities even if I add addMetaResult mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables:

```
users - id, firstName, lastName
posts - id, title, content, user_id
```

I'm trying to load entities with native query:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Entity\Post', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'title', 'title');
$rsm->addMetaResult('p', 'user_id', 'user_id');
$sql = 'select p.id, p.title, p.user_id from posts p';
$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);    
$posts = $query->getResult();
```

Doctrine loads "Post" entity, and fills "User" relation, but all attributes of "User" entity is NULL. Why it doesn't load "User" entity with proxy object? For what does "addMetaResult" exists?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you call get_class on "User", than you'll see that it is a doctrine proxy. All attributes are nulls because proxy is not loaded. Call on of "getter" methods (for example getFirstName()) on one of attribute and doctrine will load class and fill all other attributes.